# Can insert React JSX <Link> with innerHTML method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, innerhtml

I have some html (JSX) in my react app that looks like this:

```
<div><h3>Title</h3><p> some message...</p></div>
```

I am then assigning this to a variable called msg using innerHTML like so:

```
let msg
msg.innerHTML = "<div><h3>Title</h3><p> some message...</p></div>"
//then i append it to my app like this
document.body.appendChild(msg)
```

Now i would like to surround the html above with a native React Link element like so

```
msg.innerHTML = "<Link to"/"><div><h3>Title</h3><p> some message...</p></div></Link>"
```

of course it doesn't work and it is compiled as regular html when it is rendered to the page as  and doesn't act as a react link

How can i achieve this, is it even possible or is there a totally different way of approaching this issue?

I tried doing this and many different variations but to no cigar:

```
msg.innerHTML = `${<Link to"/">}<div><h3>Title</h3><p> some message...</p></div>${</Link}`
```

Answer (score 3):

There is [`ReactDOMServer.renderToString`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) that will render a React element to its initial HTML.

```js
...
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const msg = document.createElement("div");
    msg.innerHTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
      <Link to="/">
        <div>
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p> some message...</p>
        </div>
      </Link>
    );

    document.body.appendChild(msg);
  }, []);

  return null;
}
```

[image: Edit angry-leavitt-cvod1]

Comment: this code is helpful. it works except the state that i am setting onclick of this element isn't getting updated.

Comment: please elaborate your question, you didn't mention you have event listeners. Or provide a codesandbox so that we can see your actual codes.

Comment: yes i have an event listener on it that when clicked it sets the state of "added", which causes all elements with state: added to appear on this new page. But with this Link thing you provided, it goes to the page but it doesnt set the state.

Comment: You have `onClick` on `Link` component?

Comment: no. here is the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/firestack-e4syp?file=/src/comps/MovieItem.js

Comment: In the app, when you click on the plus icon on any movie, the notification at the bottom needs to have a link to the watchlist component.

Comment: Thanks for providing a codesandbox. what's the `to` value for watchlist component?

Comment: to="/Watchlist"

Comment: This is the issue you're trying to fix now `You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`?

Comment: i changed the code to include the Link inside the router but it still does the same thing. It seems like when you click on this Link it reloads the app and brings us to a new page so the state is lost.

Comment: Don't use the `Link` component, I created on my codesandbox. You should use the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`.